# Решение нелинейного уравнения при вызове функции с двумя переменными

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sympy

Для примера есть следующий код, который решает нелинейное уравнение:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def f(x):
    return 2*x**2+3*x-10

x = fsolve(f, 1)
print(x)
```

Как решить такое же уравнение, если у функции будет второй аргумент, передаваемый извне?

```
def f(x, add):
    return 2*x**2+3*x-add
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def f(x, add):
    return 2*x**2+3*x-add
s = float(input())
x = fsolve(f, 1, s)
print(x)
```